# Derivatives in the SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics package

Tags: special-functions, packages

Hello I'm using the SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics package from the [Black Hole Perturbation Toolkit](http://bhptoolkit.org/toolkit.html)
.

This package includes the `SpinWeightedSphericalHarmonicY`, which takes 5 arguments. If we input the first three arguments (usually denoted $s,l,m$) as integers the function evaluates into Mathematica's function (concretly combinations of `Exp, Sin, Cos`).
Now in my application I calculated derivatives of these harmonics at a point, but these don't evaluate anymore.

I have the code

```
<< SpinWeightedSpheroidalHarmonics`
D[SpinWeightedSphericalHarmonicY[s, l, m, x, y], x]/.{s->-1,l->1,m->0,x->\[pi]/2,y->0}
(*SpinWeightedSphericalHarmonicY^(0,0,0,1,0))[-1,1,0,\[Pi]/2,0] *)
```

But what I would want to get is

```
SpinWeightedSphericalHarmonicY[s, l, m, x, y] /. {s -> -1, l -> 4, m -> 0, y -> 0}
D[%, x] /. x -> \[Pi]/2
(*-((9 Sqrt[5/\[Pi]])/8)*)
```

So my question is basically how do I turn the output of the first code into the second?
I've tried playing around with `UpSet`, but I've had no luck

Comment: Have you already tried e-mailing the authors of that toolkit?

Comment: No I first asked here. 
It seemed to me that it should be possible to fix by some clever use of 'UpSet' or something similar.